# CSV input, powershell pulling $null value rows from targeted column

Tags: powershell, csv, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a script to create Teams in Microsoft Teams from data in a CSV file.

The CSV file has the following columns: `Team_name, Team_owner, Team_Description, Team_class`

The script should grab `Team_name` row value and use that value to create a variable. Use that variable to query if it exists in Teams and if not, create it using the data in the other columns.

The problem I am having is my `foreach` loop seems to be collecting rows without values. I simplified the testing by first trying to identify the values and monitoring the output.

Here is the test script

```
$Team_infocsv = Import-csv -path $path Teams_info.csv

# $Team_infocsv | Foreach-object{

foreach($line in $Team_infocsv){
    $owner = $line.Team_owner
    Write-Host "Team Owner: $owner"
    $teamname = $line.Team_name
    Write-Host "Team Name: $teamname"
    $team_descr = $line.Team_Description
    Write-Host "Team Description: $team_descr"
    $teamclass = $line.Team_class
    Write-Host "Team Class: $teamclass"
}
```

I only have two rows of data but yet returned are the two lines as requested with extra output (from rows) without values.

Comment: the output looks like this:Team Name: Test-team 
Team Description: Testing automation 1
Team Owner: jsmith
Team Class: Private
Team Name: Test-Team2 
Team Description: Testing automation 2
Team Owner: jsmoe
Team Class: Public
Team Description: 
Team Owner: 
Team Class: 
Team Description: 
Team Owner: 
Team Class: 
Team Description: 
Team Owner: 
Team Class: 
Team Description: 
Team Owner: 
Team Class:

Comment: You should delete your comment and put that information into your question in a better readable format. BTW you don't need to create the variables inside the for, directly put them in the write-host command like thisl `Write-Host "Team Ownwe: $($line.Team_owner)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with your code per se, except:

- `Teams_info.csv` is specified *in addition* to `$path` after `Import-Csv -Path`, which I presume is a typo, however.
- `$path` could conceivably - and accidentally - be an *array* of file paths, and if the additional file(s) has entirely different columns, you'd get empty values for the first file's columns.

If not, the issue must be with the contents of `Teams_info.csv`, so I suggest you examine that; piping to `Format-Custom` as shown below will also you help you detect the case where `$path` is unexpectedly an *array* of file paths:

Here's a working example of a CSV file resembling your input - created ad hoc - that you can compare to your input file.

```
# Create sample file.
@'
"Team_name","Team_owner","Team_Description","Team_class"
"Team_nameVal1","Team_ownerVal1","Team_DescriptionVal1","Team_classVal1"
"Team_nameVal2","Team_ownerVal2","Team_DescriptionVal2","Team_classVal2"
'@ > test.csv

# Import the file and examine the objects that get created.
# Note the use of Format-Custom.
Import-Csv test.csv test.csv | Format-Custom
```

The above yields:

```
class PSCustomObject
{
  Team_name = Team_nameVal1
  Team_owner = Team_ownerVal1
  Team_Description = Team_DescriptionVal1
  Team_class = Team_classVal1
}

class PSCustomObject
{
  Team_name = Team_nameVal2
  Team_owner = Team_ownerVal2
  Team_Description = Team_DescriptionVal2
  Team_class = Team_classVal2
}
```

[`Format-Custom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-custom) produces a custom view (a non-table and non-list view) as defined by the type of the instances being output; in the case of the `[pscustomobject]` instances that `Import-Csv` outputs you get the above view, which is a convenient way of getting at least a quick sense of the objects' content (you may still have to dig deeper to distinguish empty strings from `$null`s, ...).

Comment: Thanks. I recreated the csv file and am now able to pull the rows with values only. Now the issue I am having is with the Microsoft-Teams module "new-team -displayname $teamname" not  recognizing my variable.                                                                                         
 Error: New-Team : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'DisplayName'. Specified method is not 
supported.

Comment: @EveretteLamb: That suggests that variable `$teamname` contains an _array_ of strings, whereas `New-Team` expects a _single_ string.